# How to make a Textarea act like a password field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a textarea look like a password field. In webkit browsers I have found below attribute to make it

```
-webkit-text-security : circle
```

But it does not work in other browsers. Any cross browser alternative for this...?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a ... password field?

Comment: @Oded: Just a guess, but a password field can't be multi-line?

Comment: @Joel - possibly, that's why I asked...

Comment: @Oded Yes, I cannot use password field.  I need it to be multi line..

Comment: For a large amount of text, in particular multi-line, having it show up as text in a password field is not very user friendly (how do users know if they have made any mistakes? how do users _correct_ mistakes?).

Comment: Why would you need it to be multiline? I honestly don't understand the concept of a multiline password. You can use multiple password fields though..

Comment: @Oded Yes I agree with you. But if it is like providing feedback of an Organization in a open survey...

Comment: Why would having it as a password field make any difference to security? The text is stored plain - if you want to transmit it securely, use `https`.

Comment: @Oded I just wanted to make it invisible to other employees while some employee is entering data

Comment: @SoI — First bit of feedback: "Give us a working environment where we can expect not to have all our work read over our shoulders"

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385951/9487934

Comment: See this answer this may be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77186040/5970065

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS for this, define a variable and store textarea value in that and replace contents in textarea with any special character. You 'll have actual value in JS variable which could be used to submit the form or validate etc.

For this, you can write a function for `keydown` event.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but the implementation is not trivial. The idea is to use an invisible `password=true` input element as a state/proxy for the password-masked version of your textarea, and use JS to switch the password-masked (fake) textarea with a real textarea on show/hide.

**Something to note:** a comment by [intgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177663/intgr) on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058008/is-there-a-known-way-to-have-a-textarea-with-the-password-type) states,

> Unfortunately this gets ugly very quickly. A normal password field
>   also allows modifications in the middle, copy-cut-paste, drag & drop,
>   and probably other behaviors that I couldn't think of. Emulating all
>   of these faithfully, even if possible, probably would not be worth the
>   trouble.

My implementation avoids this complexity by programmatically disabling text navigation via click or arrow keys in the password-masked (fake) textarea. The real textarea can be navigated and edited within however, so there's very little lost in terms of UX.

Check out my implementation below:

```js
// element handles
const inp = document.getElementById("input-el");
const fta = document.getElementById("fake-textarea-el");
const ftac = document.getElementById("fake-textarea-el-content");
const rta = document.getElementById("real-textarea-el");
const toggle = document.getElementById("pw-toggle");

// initial text element height
const initialHeightPx = fta.clientHeight + 'px';

// show/hide content flag
let hideContent = true;

// util for minimum textarea height workaround
function textWidth(text) {
  const tag = document.createElement('div');
  tag.classList.add('hidden');
  tag.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
  tag.innerHTML = text;

  document.body.appendChild(tag);
  const result = tag.clientWidth;
  
  document.body.removeChild(tag);
  
  return result;
}

function setTextArea(content = '') {
  // update all text elements
  ftac.innerHTML = content.replace(/./g, '•');
  inp.value = content;
  rta.value = content;

  // workaround to use CSS height for minimum
  // textarea height
  let newHeight = initialHeightPx;
  if (textWidth(content) > rta.clientWidth) {
    rta.style.height = 'auto';
    newHeight = rta.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
  rta.style.height = newHeight;
}

function handleInput(e) {
  const {target: {value}} = e;
  setTextArea(value);
}

inp.oninput = handleInput;
rta.oninput = handleInput;

fta.onfocus = e => {
  inp.focus();
  
  fta.classList.add('has-focus');
  ftac.classList.remove('has-selectall');
}

inp.onblur = e => {
  // deselect input contents
  inp.selectionStart = inp.selectionEnd = -1;
  
  fta.classList.remove('has-focus');
  ftac.classList.remove('has-selectall');
}

inp.onkeydown = e => {
  const {charCode, keyCode, target: {value}} = e;
  const code = keyCode || charCode;
  
  // prevent arrow keys
  if (code >= 37 && code <= 40) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  // handle ctrl/meta key combinations
  if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
    switch (e.key) {
      case 'a':
        e.preventDefault();
        inp.setSelectionRange(0, inp.value.length)
        fta.classList.remove('has-focus');
        ftac.classList.add('has-selectall');
        break;
      default:
    }
  } else if (ftac.classList.contains('has-selectall')) {
    fta.classList.add('has-focus');
    ftac.classList.remove('has-selectall');
  }
}

// handle show/hide toggle
toggle.onclick = e => {
  hideContent = !hideContent;
  
  if (hideContent) {
    rta.classList.add('hidden');
    fta.classList.remove('hidden');
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Show';
  } else {
    fta.classList.add('hidden');
    rta.classList.remove('hidden');
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Hide';
  }
}
```

```css
/* SETUP BEGIN */
* {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  height: 24px;
  margin: 18px;
  width: 60px;
}
/* SETUP END */


#fake-textarea-el, #real-textarea-el {
  border: none; /* remove user-agent textarea border */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: none;
  width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#fake-textarea-el {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 24px;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -1000;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.has-selectall {
  /* default selection bg on MacOS + Chrome */
  background: #ACCEF7;
}

.cursor {
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 1rem;
}

.has-focus .cursor {
  animation: cursorBlink 1.14s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes cursorBlink {
  0% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  51% {
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input id="input-el" class="hidden" type="password" />
  <div id="fake-textarea-el" contenteditable>
    <span id="fake-textarea-el-content"></span><span class="cursor"></span>
  </div>
  <textarea id="real-textarea-el" class="hidden"></textarea>
  <button id="pw-toggle">Show</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make such component recently, here is my implementation:

```
     //get your textarea
     var textarea = document.getElementById('#textarea');
     textarea.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
     //flag to switch between hidden and not-hidden state
     boolean showChars = false
     //value where real password will be stored
     var value = '';

     function onKeyDown(e) {
        if (e.code === 'Enter') {
            //disable next line char; I did not handle situation
            //when user copy-paste text with next line char
            e.preventDefault();
            textarea.submit();
            return;
        }
        if(showChars) {
            value = e.target.value;
            return;
        }
        var selectionStart = e.target.selectionStart
        var selectionEnd = e.target.selectionEnd
        var allowed = ["Digit", "Key"];
        var char = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < allowed.length; i++) {
            if(e.code.indexOf(allowed[i]) === 0) {
                char = e.key;
                break;
            }
        }
        var onDelete = false;
        if(e.code === 'Backspace') {
            onDelete = true;
            selectionStart = Math.max(0, selectionStart - 1);
        } else if(e.code === 'Delete') {
            onDelete = true;
            selectionEnd = Math.min(textarea.value.length, selectionEnd + 1);
        }

        value = value.substring(0, selectionStart) + char + value.substring(selectionEnd);
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, selectionStart) + (char ? '•' : '') + textarea.value.substring(selectionEnd);

        setCaretPosition(textarea, selectionStart + (onDelete ? 0 : 1))
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

 //copy-pasted function to set caret position
 function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a jQuery plugin like : http://blog.decaf.de/2009/07/iphone-like-password-fields-using-jquery/

Comment: like @Oded said, it's not user-friendly but I guess you know that :)