# Text area masked as password

Tags: html, input, passwords, textarea

Is it possible to style or mask text area html element, thus it appears as input element of type password.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to use JavaScript, but it'd be ugly.

Comment: you probably could play around with custom fonts, the similar way http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ does, here is bin with win 8 build wingdings illustrating idea http://jsbin.com/onesah/1/edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Textarea act like a password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895774/how-to-make-a-textarea-act-like-a-password-field)