# Is there a known way to have a textarea with the password type?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, fonts

So I am currently trying to get a textarea with the password type (actually like an input).

I've try to create my own font (with only black points) but it's a bit hard...

I've tried some Jquery but that was not concluant either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you want a password to be in multiple lines?

Comment: It's not for a password it's for a secret message. Currently I use JQuery as you can see : http://alpha.harrywishyouwell.com/ but that's not perfect.

Comment: This is like Alpha prototype of this concept. I could never imagine using that to write anything more than 2 words and feel confident that I didn't write bunch of gibberish.

Comment: Just because the message is "secret" you do not need to mask the input. Actually it would be a horrible user interface...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Textarea act like a password field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895774/how-to-make-a-textarea-act-like-a-password-field)

Comment: @Joonas, Imagine you want to write something very short that would harm your reputation if it is read by someone else, the usages are multiple but I totaly understand if you find it useless.

Comment: Melki: I don't find the concept useless, but the execution of it stinks. To be honest, I'm not so sure this can be handled any better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post:
[How to make a Textarea act like a password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895774/how-to-make-a-textarea-act-like-a-password-field)

mentions using the keydown event to replace things in the box with whatever you want.  Of course, you'll need to store the entered text in some javascript variable at the same time.

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385951/9487934

Answer (score 11):

You can use CSS to blur the text instead.

```
style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"
```

Comment: It works awesome! Very smart!

Comment: Clever, but not ideal if the user needs to type into it, as it's too hard to see how many characters you've already typed

Answer (score 2):

I Hope you can get idea from

http://jsfiddle.net/X37Wz/6/

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="field"  onKeyPress="handleTyping(event)">
</textarea>

<textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="hiddenfield"  style="display:none">
</textarea>


function handleTyping(e){
    setTimeout(function(){handleTypingDelayed(e)},500);
}

function handleTypingDelayed(e){

    var text = document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value;
    var stars = document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value.length;
    unicode = eval(unicode);
    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

    if ( (unicode >=65 && unicode <=90) 
            || (unicode >=97 && unicode <=122) 
                || (unicode >=48 && unicode <=57) ){
        text = text+String.fromCharCode(unicode);    
        stars += 1;
    }else{
        stars -= 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value = text;
    document.getElementById('field').value = generateStars(stars);
}

function generateStars(n){
    var stars = '';
    for (var i=0; i<n;i++){
        stars += '.';
    }
    return stars;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gets ugly very quickly. A normal password field also allows modifications in the middle, copy-cut-paste, drag & drop, and probably other behaviors that I couldn't think of. Emulating all of these faithfully, even if possible, probably would not be worth the trouble.