# having a text area password field in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

How is it possible to have a text area in GWT with a multiline password? 
I would like to have a text area where the text is not visible (with stars)

I am using :

> com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.PasswordItem

Comment: Does [setRowSpan](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setRowSpan-int-) not help? Why do you want to have a multi line password field at all?

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach not really! We just need to provide an encrypted password that could be a multiline value

Comment: I do not get it sorry. Multi line text fields are useful when you want to have longer text which then will be better readable -> this makes no sense for a password field. Because of that I suspect that you will not be successful finding a predefined component and probably have to implement it by yourself. But because I am quite curious: can you please explain the target you want to achieve with that? Should the password include control characters like `newline`? Or should the user be able to count the already entered characters?

Comment: See [Is there a known way to have a textarea with the password type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058008/is-there-a-known-way-to-have-a-textarea-with-the-password-type).