# mask all entered text in textarea in password format e.g. ********

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<textarea id="txt_area" class="TextArea" name="textarea"  maxlength="256"></textarea>
```

at run time when user try to enter anything inside the above text area, it should display password format or special characters e.g.: *********

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why not use input type `password` for passwords?

Comment: You want to create a password field of 256 char?

Comment: No I want to enter input characters in text area in password format

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385951/9487934 The only functionality lost is the ability to navigate/delete/select text in the middle of the field while it's password-masked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Textarea act like a password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895774/how-to-make-a-textarea-act-like-a-password-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code where you can create new password input and add value to it

```
 $('#txt_area').after('<input id="password_input" type="password"></input>');
 $('#password_input').val($('#txt_area').val());
//to remove text area
$('#txt_area').remove();
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48kqc4Lc/8/)**

Comment: but the size of text area will effect from this.?

Comment: there is not such default maxlength limit for password, but it is not setting value of text area to password input. let me check

Comment: I have updated my answer and reading text area value using `.val()` instead of `.text()` (which was causing problem). See demo link also.

Comment: could you please check again my question after modification.?

Comment: Do you want to mask all entered text in textarea?

Comment: Yes  Bhushan Kawadkar

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the MVC html helper (I noticed you tagged this as MVC 3) :

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
```